# Disallowing .php in urls

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm using htaccess to create SEO-friendly URLs like so:

```
RewriteRule ^search/page/(.*)$ /search.php?page=$1
```

So that works great.  When I type in /search/page/2/ it redirects correctly. But people can still access it by typing /search.php?page=2.  How can I disallow that?  And should it be sent to the 404 page or back to the /search/page/2/?

Answer (score 0):

Try this to redirect to the new URL:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} page=(.*)
RewriteRule ^search.php /search/page/%1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Hmm that returns /search/page/?page=2 for me.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=(.*)
RewriteRule ^search.php /search/page/%1/? [R,L]
```